# How to make fake placeholder go up on focus

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/428bh5r2/1/): And here is my code:

```css
.accountbox {
    background-color:#ffffff;
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 padding: 15px 120px 50px 50px; 
}

:focus{outline: none;}

.input1div {
 display:inline-block;  position: relative;
}

.input1div input {
 font: 15px/24px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif; color: #333; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.input1div input {border: 0; padding: 7px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}

.input1div input ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.input1div input:focus ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}


 .fakeplaceholder {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.28s ease all;
}

.firstname:focus ~ .fakeplaceholder{
  top: -10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="accountbox">
    
    <form class="accountform">
  
        <div class="input1div">
            <input class="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="" />
      <span class="fakeplaceholder">First Name</span> 
       <span class="focus-border"></span>
     </div>
     
    </form>

</div>
```

If you click on the `input` box, then the `.fakeplaceholder` will go up.

But I want something more:

Expected result:

1. On focus, fakeplaceholder will go up ---- WORKING
2. If the user type some text in it, and then remove the focus, it will stay up -- Not working

I tried to use this code, in order to achieve what I want, but it does not work (test it out)

```
.firstname:not(:focus):valid ~ .fakeplaceholder{
  top: -10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('.firstname');
var placeholder = document.querySelector('.fakeplaceholder');

input.addEventListener('change',function(){
  if(this.value == ''){
    placeholder.classList.remove('isValid');
  }else{
    placeholder.classList.add('isValid');
  }
})
```

```css
.accountbox {
    background-color:#ffffff;
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 padding: 15px 120px 50px 50px; 
}

:focus{outline: none;}

.input1div {
 display:inline-block;  position: relative;
}

.input1div input {
 font: 15px/24px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif; color: #333; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.input1div input {border: 0; padding: 7px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}

.input1div input ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.input1div input:focus ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}


 .fakeplaceholder {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.28s ease all;
}

.firstname:focus ~ .fakeplaceholder{
  top: -10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
  color:red;
}

.isValid{
  top: -10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="accountbox">
    <form class="accountform">
        <div class="input1div">
            <input class="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="" />
   <span class="fakeplaceholder">First Name</span> 
   <span class="focus-border"></span>
  </div>
    </form>
</div>
```